# faster download: png or svg?

Tags: http, svg, png

I was told once that code is faster to download than image files. Is this true, or is file size the only factor that matters?

For example, I have an SVG file that is a complex illustration. This SVG file is 3.5mb, after optimization using SVGOMG.

I also rendered the illustration as a PNG file. The PNG version has file size of only 153k, after optimization using ImageOptim.

In this scenario, is it true that an SVG file download is faster because it is code - as opposed to a bitmap?  OR is the file size the only factor that determines download speed?

The reason I am considering SVG is to preserve the detail of the illustration.

Comment: Bytes are bytes.  What those bytes contain make no difference for downloading, except for gzip compression.

Comment: ...which will get you a factor of 4 for a typical SVG, so probably ∼1MB for your file.